# Trying to make a Rigidbody2d variable in unity for a flappy bird sort of game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my code is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    IEnumerator Wait(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
    void Start()
    {}
    public RigidBody rb;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w")){
            StartCoroutine(Wait());

        }
    }
}
```

my errors are
Assets/JumpScript.cs(13,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RigidBody' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm trying to make a flappy bird sort of game as practice for unity + c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have capitalized "RigidBody" incorrectly, it should be "Rigidbody". Also, if you are working with 2D then you should be using "Rigidbody2D". Also, I am not 100% sure what your question here is, I assume you want help to just fix that error, so there you go, change `public RigidBody rb;` to `public Rigidbody2D rb;` (if you are making a 2D game you should be using Rigidbody2D).

Answer (score 0):

it is `Rigidbody` not `RigidBody` you spell it incorrectly

if you are working with a 2D game you should use `Rigidbody2D` not `Rigidbody`

and for 3D game, you must use `Rigidbody`

make sure you have imported `using UnityEngine;`

change `public RigidBody rb;` to `public Rigidbody rb;`

Comment: @AeneasTheBadDeveloper if it works plese upvote and mark it as accepted thanx